# where do i create the config file (php client)

Tags: php, rest

I found this [script](https://github.com/repat/plentymarkets-rest-client) on the internet unfortunately the connection does not work (404 error) I have created the config file in the same folder as the project (I use phpstorm). I still have to set a path in the script or what exactly am I doing wrong here ?

[image]

this is my config.php

```
 $config = [
 "username" => "***",
 "password" => "***",
 "url" => "***",
 ];
```

Answer (score -1):

It loads relatively to your application run entry point. If you want, you can specify the absolute path so it should work fine:

```php
$configFilePath = dirname(__FILE__).'/config.php';
```